# How to translate PHP file to model in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I translate this PHP file to model file? I'm new in CodeIgniter.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $q=$_GET['q'];
    $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
    $mysqli=mysqli_connect('192.168.128.30','root','root','root') or die("Database Error");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemcode LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY itemcode";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    if($result)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo $row['itemcode']."\n";

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: look at here it will help you.
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only **CI Model** ? This's yours :

```
public function select_data($my_data){
   $this->db->like('itemcode', $my_data);
   $this->db->order_by('itemcode');

   return $this->db->get('items');
}
```

Comment: Then in your controller, do something like `$data['items'] = $this->{modelname}->select_data($my_data);` 

Make sure you pass $data var when loading view. In your view you can then just use `$items`

Comment: thank you for your help guys sorry for my bad codes just new in codeigniter thank you

Comment: You are welcome @user2750367 .. Fell free to learn at [CI Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/), especially [CI active record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select) :)

Answer (score 1):

If your table name is items then you can create a php file named mitems.php.
There is an example of model file...

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MItems extends CI_Model
{
    public $table;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table = "items";
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function select($conditions=NULL, $tablename="", $limit=500, $offset=0)
    {
        if($tablename=="")
        {
            $tablename = $this->table;
        }
        if($conditions != NULL)
            $this->db->where($conditions);

        $query = $this->db->get($tablename, $limit, $offset=0);
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

You can follow this link http://thephpcode.com/blog/codeigniter/a-smart-codeigniter-model

Answer (score 0):

Some basic thoughts:

- You could create a model class "ItemCode" or something like that (don't know the subject) and add a method `Search`;
- You could use the built in "DB" object to execute the query, see http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select ;
- accessing the "GET" parameters should be moved to the controller and you should use something that is better aware of SQL injections (in ActiveRecord like's case, this will be escaped automatically);
- SQL connection parameters should only be found in configuration files.